# Why porcelain Insulators are brown in colour?

Tags: electricity

The porcelain insulators are brown in colour. Why?

Comment: This reads a bit like a trivial question. If it is intended as a physics question it should probably be clarified.

Answer (score 3):

In my country they are white for domestic use. So it must be a colorant.